Microsoft Omnichannel SDK - Issue connecting chat widget via chatSDK.startChat()
I'm trying to connect to my chat widget via the Omnichannel SDK but running into an issue when starting the chat.

I'm able to create a new chat sdk ( const chatSDK = new OmnichannelChatSDK(omnichannelConfig);)
I'm able top successfully initialize (chatSDK.initialize()`)
It always fails on chatsSDK.startChat() with the error: ChatSDKError {message: 'MessagingClientConversationJoinFailure', httpResponseStatusCode: undefined} - the error happens here:

      try {
        await chatSDK?.startChat(optionalParams);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`ERROR=====`, error);
        return;
      }


This is as far it gets each time:


I've configured the Omnichannel chat widget already and am able to connect using the sandbox site provided by the Omnichannel SDK repo: https://vvfog.csb.app/?orgId=[orgId]&orgUrl=[orgUrl]&widgetId=[widgetId]
I essentially used the exact same code from the demo site sandbox to implement within my application

Specs:

Using "@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-sdk": "^1.8.1-main.e44745c", (also tried v1.5.5 (the same being used in the demo site)
The rest of my package.json:

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
    "@dmi/shared": "0.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-sdk": "^1.8.1-main.e44745c",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "6.8.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "dotenv": "6.1.0",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.1.0",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.0",
    "immer": "7.0.8",
    "inquirer-recursive": "0.0.6",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "jss": "10.0.4",
    "koa-webpack-middleware": "1.0.7",
    "loadable-components": "2.2.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.20",
    "lottie-web": "5.7.6",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dates": "21.8.0",
    "react-dnd": "7.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "7.0.2",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-dropzone": "12.0.4",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "2.1.0",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "4.6.4",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^6.1.6",
    "react-redux": "7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "8.0.0",
    "styled-components": "5.1.1",
    "victory": "36.2.0",
    "warning": "4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "7.4.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "6.12.2",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
    "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "coveralls": "3.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.6.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.7.1",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "6.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
    "node-plop": "0.18.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "offline-plugin": "5.0.6",
    "plop": "2.3.0",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
    "react-test-context-provider": "2.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "6.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "shelljs": "0.8.3",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.6.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.47.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  }

Help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if there's any other info needed. Thank you.

What was tried is described above

